# The viewing session is not available or has expired when calling Birt Report

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, birt

I'm trying to call Birt report from a controller as following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/birtReport", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation("Download Report")
public void birtReport(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ErrorExceptions, IOException{
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8080/birt/run?__report=MyFirstReport.rptdesign&id=211");
        HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
        InputStream body = response1.getEntity().getContent();
        IOUtils.copy(body, response.getOutputStream());
        response.flushBuffer();

    }
```

What I'm really doing is calling a controller that call the birt report that exist on another Tomcat server but I'm getting the following error:

> Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The viewing session is not available or has expired.
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.createRunAndRenderTask(ReportEngineService.java:1042)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.ReportEngineService.runAndRenderReport(ReportEngineService.java:911)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.BirtViewerReportService.runAndRenderReport(BirtViewerReportService.java:973)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.__execute(BirtGetPageAllActionHandler.java:131)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.service.actionhandler.AbstractBaseActionHandler.execute(AbstractBaseActionHandler.java:90)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.__executeAction(AbstractBaseDocumentProcessor.java:47)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.executeAction(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:143)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.BirtDocumentProcessor.handleGetPageAll(BirtDocumentProcessor.java:183)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.processor.AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.process(AbstractBaseComponentProcessor.java:112)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.soapengine.endpoint.BirtSoapBindingImpl.getUpdatedObjects(BirtSoapBindingImpl.java:66)
   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor577.invoke(Unknown Source)
   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.invokeMethod(RPCProvider.java:397)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.RPCProvider.processMessage(RPCProvider.java:186)
   at org.apache.axis.providers.java.JavaProvider.invoke(JavaProvider.java:323)
   at org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.doVisiting(SimpleChain.java:118)
   at org.apache.axis.SimpleChain.invoke(SimpleChain.java:83)
   at org.apache.axis.handlers.soap.SOAPService.invoke(SOAPService.java:454)
   at org.apache.axis.server.AxisServer.invoke(AxisServer.java:281)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:699)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.doPost(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:265)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
   at org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServletBase.service(AxisServletBase.java:327)
   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.service(BirtSoapMessageDispatcherServlet.java:122)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   at org.eclipse.birt.report.filter.ViewerFilter.doFilter(ViewerFilter.java:68)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:475)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:651)
   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:500)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:754)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1376)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And is that the best way to call Birt reports from an API?

Answer (score 1):

i was able to solve my problem by using report engine and that's the controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/birtReport1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ApiOperation("Download Report")
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        //get report name and launch the engine
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
//      resp.setContentType( "application/pdf" ); 
        //resp.setHeader ("Content-Disposition","inline; filename=test.pdf");       
        String reportName = "/Documents/workspace/Birt/MyFirstReport.rptdesign";
        ServletContext sc = req.getSession().getServletContext();
        this.birtReportEngine = BirtEngine.getBirtEngine(sc);
        IReportRunnable design;
        try
        {
            //Open report design
            design = birtReportEngine.openReportDesign( reportName );
            //create task to run and render report
            IRunAndRenderTask task = 
            birtReportEngine.createRunAndRenderTask( design );      
            String[] values = {"10096", "10094"};
            task.setParameterValue("idCatalogue",values);
            HTMLRenderOption options = new HTMLRenderOption();
        options.setOutputFormat(HTMLRenderOption.OUTPUT_FORMAT_HTML);
            options.setOutputStream(resp.getOutputStream());
            task.setRenderOption(options);

            //run report
            task.run();
            task.close();
        }catch (Exception e){

            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ServletException( e );
        }
    }
```